# How to clear Android Canvas? .drawColor and erasing paths are not working

Tags: java, android, canvas, graphics, drawing

I originally tried erasing paths as they were drawn, but drawn paths were not added to array correctly (Though getting rid of the for loop that cycles through the same array causes the application to not work any more). Because of this I'm just going to try erasing the whole canvas and starting over.

Below is my code for a DrawView class:

```
package com.example.sherman.drawtranslate;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DrawView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;

    private float maxX;
    private float maxY;
    private float midX;
    private float midY;

    private float rawX;
    private float rawY;
    private float rawEndX;
    private float rawEndY;


    //paint for Back Line
    private Paint backLinePaint = new Paint();
    private Path backLinePath = new Path();
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Stroke> strokes = new ArrayList<Stroke>();

    private Bitmap im;

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();

        //draw the backline
        backLinePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        backLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(20f);

        im = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.drawtranslateicon);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        maxX = getWidth();
        maxY = getHeight();
        midX = maxX / 2;
        midY = maxY / 2;

        String screenDimensions = "Dimensions X =" + maxX + ", Y = " + maxY + ". Midpoints: X=" + midX + ", Y=" + midY + ".";
        Log.d("ONMEASURE", "onMeasure called with " + screenDimensions);

    }//end onMeasure


    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        canvas.drawLine(midX, 0, midX, maxY, backLinePaint);

    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

    }//end touch start

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }//end if touch tolerance

    }//end touch_move

    private void touch_up() {
        Log.d("ACTION_UP", "User lifted their finger");
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        rawEndX = mX;
        rawEndY = mY;

        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        paths.add(new Path(mPath));

        //make new Stroke class
        Stroke stroke = new Stroke(rawX, rawY, rawEndX, rawEndY);
        //Log.d("Stroke", "New stroke created, details: startX=" + stroke.getStartX() + ", startY = " + stroke.getStartY()
        //        + ", endX =" + stroke.getEndX() + ", endY = " + stroke.getEndY() + ".");
        Log.d("Stroke", stroke.getInfo());
        strokes.add(stroke);
        Log.d("Stroke", "Stroke slope = " + stroke.getSlope());
        Log.d("Stroke", "Stroke List size = " + strokes.size());
        mPath = new Path();
    }//end touchUp


    /**
     * onClickUndo
     *
     * Clear the canvas ,erasing any previous drawings.
     */
    public void onClickUndo() {
        Log.d("Undo Button", "Undo button pressed...");

        //try making a new canvas DOESN'T WORK
        mCanvas = null;
        mCanvas = new Canvas();

        //try drawing color -DOESN'T WORK
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);









    }//end onClickUndo

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        rawX = event.getRawX();
        rawY = event.getRawY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }

        Log.d("TOUCH", "Touch at " + rawX + ", " + rawY);

        return true;
    }//end onTouch
}//end Class
```

My MainActivity class

```
    package com.example.sherman.drawtranslate;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final DrawView drawView = new DrawView(this,null);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //listener for undo button
        Button undoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.undo);
        undoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View button) {
                drawView.onClickUndo();

            }//end undoButton
        });//end undo button listener
    }//end onCreate
}//end MainActivity
```

Comment: I'm not really sure the purpose or use of `mCanvas` -  all drawing is done when `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` is called.  As I see you are trying to reset the custom `View`? in your `onClickUndo()` method just call `paths.clear()` & `mPath.reset()` then `invalidate()`

Comment: No luck with that, shame! button tap and nothing happens, at least a screen flicker or something would show that we're getting somewhere but nothing.  
RE: mCanvas I used some code from elsewhere on Stackoverflow for a small part of this